# How to set BoxView or Frame height equal to Screen Height in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having a `BoxView` I need to set its Height and width equal to screen size. I am using `StackLayout` and setting `HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest=400`. I want the `BoxView` to fill the screen space. How can it be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Grid` and set `<RowDefinition Height="*" />`.

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black" />

</Grid>
```

If you are using nested `Grid` then set `<RowDefinition Height="*" />` in the outermost `Grid`. When you are setting Height and Width of `BoxView` same as the Screen size, then it is obvious that BoxView will take all of the screen space. Hence outermost `Grid` will have only 1 Row. Now if you want to show other UI elements on the same Page then you will have to hide the `BoxView` that was covering the UI. Hence outermost `Grid` will contain 1 Row, that will be used to show either `BoxView` or other UI elements. Just like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Black" IsVisible="True"/>

    <StackLayout Grid.Row="0" IsVisible="False">
        <Label Text="Hello"/>
    </StackLayout>

</Grid>
```

Note that you can also use nested `Grid` instead of `StackLayout` and organize your elements as per your choice.

If you want to add elements inside a `BoxView` just like Cards then use `Frame` instead.

Comment: Glad to hear that you have solved your problem by yourself, please remember to mark your reply as answer, thanks.